# C# - Error on Skip - File.ReadLines(FileNameFinal).Skip.Take(1).First()

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, visual-studio

I have this error 'System.Linq.Queryable.Skip(System.Linq.IQueryable, int)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context.

It is just going to read a file and then read the 15th line but i get the error as above.

Please Help

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FileManager
{
public class OpenFile
{
    public static string FileNameFinal;
    public static string GetFileName(string FileName);


    public static string line = File.ReadLines(FileNameFinal).Skip.Take(1).First();
}
}
```

Comment: [`Enumerable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) is a method. How do you call a method in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `.Skip.`
As the error specified `Skip` is a method, and therefor should be called as one: `Skip(3)` (the `3` is just en example for an argument)

You need to specify How many items you want to skip.
Try something like:

```
 public static string line = File.ReadLines(FileNameFinal).Skip(3).Take(1).First();
```

for skipping the first 3 items.

You can take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) for more details about the method.

Comment: Thanks it was just a typo, meant to put the brackets!

Answer (score 1):

`Skip` require int parameter.

**SKIP** : how many value it will skip

provide value to it like Skip(10) which will skip 10 values

```
public static string line = File.ReadLines(FileNameFinal).Skip(10).Take(1).First();
```

Comment: Thanks it was just a typo, meant to put the brackets!